# Does StringContentProvider set Content-Type header in HTTP request?

Tags: http-headers, jetty, firebase-cloud-messaging, content-type, jetty-9

I am trying to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging by Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) with the help of [Jetty HTTP client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/http-client.html):

```
public static final String FCM_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
public static final String FCM_KEY = "key=AAAA....";

private final HttpClient mHttpClient = new HttpClient();
private final CompleteListener mFcmListener = new CompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isFailed()) {
            // TODO delete FCM token in database for certain responses
        }
    }
};

mHttpClient.start();
mHttpClient.POST(FCM_URL)
    .header(HttpHeader.AUTHORIZATION, FCM_KEY)
    .content(new StringContentProvider(notificationStr), "application/json")
    .send(mFcmListener);
```

My question is very simple, but I couldn't find the answer myself yet by looking at the [StringContentProvider](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/client/util/StringContentProvider.java) and its base classes -

If I need to set the request HTTP header for FCM:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

then do I have to add the line:

```
.header(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
```

or will that class already do it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A couple of points:**

- Yes, if you don't set content type header explicitly, it would be auto set based on the [selected](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate/jetty-all/9.2.8.v20150217/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpConnection.java#115) Content Provider.
- By default, the StringContentProvider sets Content-Type to text/plain. To override, you need to use another constructor -

  *new StringContentProvider("application/json", content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);*
- Request [#setContent](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client/9.3.2.v20150730/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpRequest.java#587) method auto sets Content-Type header to the provided value. Hence, you need not make any change to the code.

Comment: Improved formatting. Any improvements to this answer are welcome.